# Fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04 not loading on Asus X99-E WS SOFTWARE RAID 1

Tags: server, raid

I have TWO 1TB drives configured as SOFTWARE RAID 1 using the Asus X99-E WS motherboard. 
Both Drives are connected to the Asmedia SATA controller instead of the Intel SATA controller. I intend to use the Intel controller for RAID 5 at a later stage after ensuring the Ubuntu Server OS is stable.

What i did:

1. Pop in the installation disc Ubuntu Server 14.04 and started the installation, created SOFTWARE RAID 1 on both the hard drives using this guide:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=at5PXtrbzfs 
   Installation was smooth.
   I continued with the installation till it prompts for a restart.
2. Upon restart, the GRUB menu will load, selected Ubuntu Server and continued.
   However, the loading stops halfway when running one of the scripts.
   The pic below is where the loading stops. It stays there forever.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/67qk656lqwk33yk/err.jpg?dl=0

Can anyone provide me some guidance on what error that is?
Let me know if you need more info.